# Windows server 2008 зеркалирование

Tags: windows

Добрый день.Появилась задача - настроить зеркалирование трафика на *windows server 2008*. Усиленный гуглинг не помогает, информации в сети найти не могу. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать.

Небольшой апдейт: подумал что проблему можно решить с помощью бриджей. Только не могу найти информации  по поводу того как сделать хаб из бриджа (установить `ageing time` в `0`), в *linux* это делается с помощью `brctl setageing br0 0` в windows никак аналогов не найду. Может ли кто то помочь с этим?

Comment: Это же проще сделать на управляемом свитче, необходимо ли это делать именно на винде?

Comment: @ArcherGodson, именно винда, к сожалению(.

Comment: Проще повторитель (хаб), перед ним поставить, иначе, придется писать самому.